# c# winform : override default properties in designer from custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls, windows-forms-designer

Here is the situation. I made a custom button control :

```cs
public partial class EButton : Control, IButtonControl
```

This control contains a button. I use getters/setters to edit his properties in designer, like this :

```cs
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Browsable(true)]
public UIButton Button
{
    get
    {
        return EBtn;
    }
    set
    {
        EBtn = value;
    }
}
```

Now, I can access all of my button's properties in the designer.

My problem is that no matter what I define, this is always overridden by the default properties in my control.

Example : 
In my control, the BackColor of the button is set to white.
In a specific form, I want this button red, so I set BackColor properties to red in the designer **of the form.** 
When I then reload the designer, the value has returned to White.

I don't want to make a setters for each property of the button. This is a specific control (http://www.janusys.com/controls/) and it has A LOT of useful properties which I want to adapt for each specific situation.

Does anyone know a solution ?

Comment: Take a look at Plutonix's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070817/abbreviate-serialization-in-designer You most likely have to implement a typeconverter for your new control that tells the designer how to work with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575572/when-compiling-some-property-values-are-reset-set-in-the-designer

Comment: *When I reload the designer, the value has return to White* - sounds like serialization problem. Try to inspect generated by designer file to see if this change actually get saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Button MyButtonProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.button1;
    }
    set
    {
        value = this.button1;
    }
}
```

Using the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` with `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`, you are indicating that the property consists of Content, which should have initialization code generated for each public, not hidden property of the object assigned to the property.

Here is a stand alone test:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyControls
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 15);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // MyUserControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "MyUserControl";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public Button MyButtonProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return this.button1;
            }
            set
            {
                value = this.button1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nearly that. I used what you said and now, all of my properties are reset.
What I need is use default values defines in control designer with the possibilities to change them in form designer

Comment: @Robouste I've tested the solution this way, First create a `UserControl` Then put a button on it, Then add the property, Then rebuild the solution, Then Put your `UserControl` on a form, Then set the `BackColor` of it, Then close and reopen form, the property persisted.

Comment: Yes, you are right... now I have to check all my project to reinit the button, and they are a lot of them...
Thanks for your answer, it greadly helped